# LaTeXing autofill ST3 multiple file project

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, sublime-text

I'm writing my thesis in `LaTeX` using Sublime-Text3.
Since my document is quite extensive, it's easier for me to handle it in a project. Also suggested by [LaTeXing Guide (part2)](http://docs.latexing.com/stable/tutorials/set-up-a-project.html).
My `.sublime-project` file is as follows:

```
{
"folders":
[
{
    "path": "(full path)"
}
]
"settings":
[
{
    "root": "thesis1.tex",
    "pdf": "thesis1"
}
]
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{import}
    \import{./}{packages.tex}
        \makeindex
        \makeglossaries
        \makenomenclature
    \import{./}{glossary.tex}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \import{./}{nomenclature.tex}
        \printnomenclature
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
\mainmatter
    \import{./}{Part1.tex}
    \import{./}{Part2.tex}
\printbibliography
\backmatter
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

My `packages.tex` contains:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure, afterpage, etoolbox, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, epigraph, csquotes,emptypage}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=159mm,paperheight=254mm,margin=0mm,outer=0mm,text={120mm,200mm}]{geometry}% royal octavo
\usepackage{url,titlesec,fix-cm,draftwatermark}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{thesis1.bib}
```

You also need to create at least `Part1.tex` and `Part2.tex`, which can contain anything.

First of all:

`\cite{}` does not work in the main body, neither inside Part1 nor Part2, message:

```
Status: cannot find any corresponding items
```

Second:

Suppose I `\label{}` on `Part1.tex`, if I `\ref{}` inside that document, ST pops up a window showing the options defined inside the same document, which is alright, but suppose I'm writing now on `Part2.tex` and I try to `\ref{}`, nothing shows up, and I want ST to show me the labels defined on every document inside the project.

Tried `%-*- root: thesis1.tex -*-`

Tried `include` instead of `import`.

Tried fiddling with `JSON` as per the guide on [LaTeXing official page](http://docs.latexing.com/stable/tutorials/set-up-a-project.html) but to no avail.

Comment: Unfortunately the plugin is not open source so these are just speculations: 1) the plugin looks only in the main file for bib files 2) \import is not supported. You can workaround both things by putting fake `\input` and `\addbibresource` **after** `\end{document}`: They get ignored by LaTeX but not by the plugin

Comment: Got it working by using `\input ` and the `%-*- root: thesis1.tex -*-` in every subfile method, no need to use a `.sublime_project` file or `\input`s after `\end{document}`

Comment: Yes input works, but if you want to keep using import the trick of using the input after end document is a valid workaround. What I did was to input a dummy tex file which inputed all my tex files; this dummy file was generated by listing all the tex files in the project so I would not need to manually update it every time I added a file

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by using `\input` and the `%-*- root: filename.tex -*-` in every subfile method, no need to use a `.sublime_project file` or `\input`s after `\end{document}`, although the workaround mentioned by @Bordagoil in the comments is very valid.